# log4j access in multiple packages

Tags: java, log4j

i have a n number of packages, each packages contains m number of classes.
in one of the package like com.logger , i had implemented a logger class with name log.java
We know that the class file will be created in different folders with package name.
Where can i include the log4j.Properties/log4j.xml file. Please specify for maven project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j scans some locations at startup to initialize the component.

You should place your log4j configuration file in `src/main/resources` as explained in [If using maven, usually you put log4j.properties under java or resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132389/if-using-maven-usually-you-put-log4j-properties-under-java-or-resources)