# Excluding log4j.properties from JAR using Maven and Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I've used Netbeans for some time, but not until now with Maven.

I'm trying to set up a scenario whereby two properties files (Log4J.properties, and another application-specific file) will be automatically copied to the `target` directory when the project is built.  I also want them included in the classpath, so that the application can see them.

What I don't want, is for the properties files to be incorporated into the jar itself, as this would cause a pain for those wishing to edit the files.

I've followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18918600/2539470) instructions, and everything almost works.  The properties files are copied from `src/main/resources` to `target`, the Jar can be run successfully from a command line; however, I can no longer run the project in Netbeans, as it cannot see the properties files anymore....  I get

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found

, etc... What do I need to do so that Netbeans can see these properties files at run time?

Do I need to add a classpath setting here?

```
<manifestEntries> 
    <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
</manifestEntries>
```

Or is there some setting within Netbeans itself?