# Log4j.properties not found using maven resources folder

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

I try to load a configuration for log4j using the `PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties")` method but I keep running into `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132389/if-using-maven-usually-you-put-log4j-properties-under-java-or-resources) and placed my `log4j.properties` file into the `resources` folder.

I Also edited my pom.xml like this :

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>src.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So when I run `mvn package` the target folder generated contains my .jar and my log4j.properties side by side but when I run my jar I get the file not found exception.

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

**Note :**
Please, DO NOT include the log4j.properties into the final Jar file, it will cause multiple log4j.properties files in the classpath, if someone is depending on your Jar, you may accidentally override their logging configurations, depends which Jar is loaded first.

For reference :
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-exclude-log4j-properties-in-jar-file/